# Malformed access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

In my application I am using facebook accesstoken to post a message to users fan page wall. Now while posting am getting an error like

`Malformed access token`

I am able to read the posts from fan page wall. But I cant post to wall. I am using 'Curl' to post.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

$post_url       = 'https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed';
    $data['access_token']   = 'XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ ';
    $ch             = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return                 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Post here (or somewhere else) a portion of your code...it is impossible to help you in blind.

Comment: Use the [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the token, just paste it in the text field and click "debug". You should get info about the token.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database doesn't cutoff the access_token string when saved.
I had this problem with facebook once. Are you using a varchar(xx)?

Comment: am using  data type 'text' to store the access_token.

Comment: That should do it indeed, mhh.. Are you sure you are not using the request token instead of the access token?